# Is it possible to mirror a private repository on gitlab.com using the SSH protocol?

Tags: git, ssh, gitlab, ssh-keys

Gitlab.com has an option to mirror other repository's on their own site. (Project--> Project setting--> Mirror Repository)

But when I tried to do that using the ssh protocol, the authorization failed because the repository I wanted to clone didn't recognize the public key of Gitlab.com.

The page stated:

> If your SSH repository is not publicly accessible, add the public SSH key of the GitLab server to the remote repository.

The thing is, I could not find an option to add a private key to Gitlab.com or download a public key from Gitlab.com.

Is this only possible if your own a GitLab server or did I overlook something?

Answer (score 3):

[Gitlab mirroring feature](http://feedback.gitlab.com/forums/176466-general/suggestions/4286666-mirror-git-svn-into-repo-) is [implemented recently on Nov 2015](https://about.gitlab.com/2015/11/22/gitlab-8-2-released/) but unfortunately it is available only for Gitlab Enterprise Edition:

> Repository Mirroring (EE only) If you want to maintain a mirror of a
>   repository in a GitLab instance, you can now let GitLab handle the
>   mirroring for you automatically in GitLab Enterprise Edition.

Check [the features comparison](https://about.gitlab.com/features/#enterprise)  between Community and Enterprise Editions
Either you request EE or use [gitlab-mirrors](https://github.com/samrocketman/gitlab-mirrors) scripts:

> The gitlab-mirrors project is designed to fill in a feature which is currently missing from GitLab: the ability to mirror remote repositories. 
>   gitlab-mirrors creates read only copies of remote repositories in
>   gitlab. It provides a CLI management interface for managing the
>   mirrored repositories (e.g. add, delete, update) so that an admin may
>   regularly update all mirrors using crontab. It operates by interacting
>   with the GitLab API using python-gitlab3. Also, check out this cool
>   puppet module for installing and configuring gitlab-mirrors.

Comment: I am aware the community edition doesn't have automatic mirroring. [Gitlab.com](https://about.gitlab.com/gitlab-com/) runs however the Enterprise Edition. [Source](https://about.gitlab.com/gitlab-com/)

Comment: @Tijmen what errors shows you? I tried https worked, ssh with github said github unresolved

Comment: The error is: The repository failed to update a day ago.
conq: repository access denied. deployment key is not associated with the requested repository.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

Comment: @Tijmen You should add the deploy key to your repo.  For gitlab , its in settings => deploy keys. for Github,, check https://developer.github.com/guides/managing-deploy-keys/#deploy-keys .... what server you are mirroring from?

Comment: The question I'm asking is: What is the deploy key of Gitlab.com? The public git repo site, alternative for bitbucket.org.

Comment: I'm mirroring from bitbucket.org. I know how to add deploy keys to it.

Comment: deploy key is an ssh key that you should add to your repo to grant access

Comment: add the public key of gitlab as deploykey in your bitbucket project

Comment: I know what a deploy key is. I don't know the deploy key of [gitlab.com](https://gitlab.com/explore/projects/) That is why I asked this question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98264/discussion-between-bigother-and-tijmen).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that this will work, but I reckon it's worth a try. To retrieve the public key of gitlab.com, I ran the following command:

```
nmap gitlab.com --script ssh-hostkey --script-args ssh_hostkey=all
```

The following 3 public keys can then be found in the output:

```
ssh-dss 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

ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQCsj2bNKTBSpIYDEGk9KxsGh3mySTRgMtXL583qmBpzeQ+jqCMRgBqB98u3z++J1sKlXHWfM9dyhSevkMwSbhoR8XIq/U0tCNyokEi/ueaBMCvbcTHhO7FcwzY92WK4Yt0aGROY5qX2UKSeOvuP4D6TPqKF1onrSzH9bx9XUf2lEdWT/ia1NEKjunUqu1xOB/StKDHMoX4/OKyIzuS0q/T1zOATthvasJFoPrAjkohTyaDUz2LN5JoH839hViyEG82yB+MjcFV5MU3N1l1QL3cVUCh93xSaua1N85qivl+siMkPGbO5xR/En4iEY6K2XPASUEMaieWVNTRCtJ4S8H+9

_ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 AAAAE2VjZHNhLXNoYTItbmlzdHAyNTYAAAAIbmlzdHAyNTYAAABBBFSMqzJeV9rUzU4kWitGjeR4PWSa29SPqJ1fVkhtj3Hw9xjLVXVYrU9QlYWrOLXBpQ6KWjbjTDTdDkoohFzgbEY=
```

Adding these to your repository server might allow it to authenticate the connection properly.

Comment: I tested it (added the RSA key), but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this comment](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ee/issues/98#note_3684737), the key is in `/var/opt/gitlab/.ssh/id_rsa` and `/var/opt/gitlab/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` by default. If the keys don't exist, you can create them manually with `sudo -u git -H ssh-keygen` and mashing the enter key through the prompts.

I just tried this on my gitlab-ee 8.7.2 installation and it appears to be working.

Comment: Which unfortunately only matters if you're running your own installation of gitlab-ee.